# angular material input p g text cut

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular material project and I use reactive web forms. 
In that project I have a couple mat-form-fields with input formControls (matInput).
I have seen that text with p g j etc are cut off.

[image]
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me:

```
.mat-form-field .mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  line-height: 17px;
}

.mat-form-field .mat-form-field-infix input {
  line-height: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by tweaking the input line height in the inputs in your theme.

Example:

```
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
    $font-family: 'apple-system, system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"',
    $input: mat-typography-level(inherit, 1.15, 400)
);
```

Check out https://material.angular.io/guide/typography for details.

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by adding this in your css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field .mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
}
```